# Change the colors of text and background on a navbar list

Tags: javascript, html, css, list, navbar

So , i am kind of new to this and i need some help . 
I have a list that works as a navbar , and i want to change its text color and background color whenever i scroll past the header , so it's visible all the time .

Here is the code :`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(window).scroll(function(){
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll > 300) {
     $(".nav").css("text-color" , "black");
   }
   else{
    $(".nav").css("text-color" , "white");   
   }
  })
})
```

```css
/* Fara scroll-bar */
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
/* Fonturi */
@font-face{
font-family:myfont;
src: url("fonts/Hum521It.ttf");
}
@font-face{
font-family:myfont2;
src: url("fonts/Montserrat-Medium.ttf");
}
@font-face{
font-family:myfont3;
src: url("fonts/Oswald-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face{
font-family:myfont4;
src: url("fonts/Slabo27px-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face{
font-family:myfont5;
src: url("fonts/Arapey-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face{
font-family:myfont6;
src: url("fonts/RobotoCondensed-Light.ttf");
}
@font-face{
font-family:myfont7;
src: url("fonts/RobotoCondensed-Regular.ttf");
}
@font-face{
font-family:myfont8;
src: url("fonts/Raleway-Light.ttf");
}
@font-face{
font-family:myfont9;
src: url("fonts/SourceSansPro-Regular.ttf");
}
/* Structura */
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
 background-color:white;
 margin:0;
}
header{
 background-color:black;
 height:100vh;
}
main{
 
}
footer{
 background-color:black;
 float:bottom;
 text-color:white;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
 padding:30px;
}
/* Side-nav */

/* Nav-bar */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  width:100%;
  
}
li {
  float: left;
}
li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.menu_white {
 color: white;
}
.menu_black {
 color: black;
}
/* Div-ul in care e nav-bar-ul*/
.nav {

}
/* Strike-through */
.strikethrough {
 display: inline-block;
 position: relative;
 transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1);
}
.strikethrough:after {
 content: '';
 position: absolute;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 height: 2px;
 box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,0.6);
 margin-top: -0.7em;
 background: white;
 transform-origin: center left;
 animation: strikethrough 1s 0.5s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1) 1;
 transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(.55, 0, .1, 1);
}
@keyframes strikethrough {
 from {
  transform: scaleX(0);
 }
 to {
  transform: scaleX(1);
 }
}
.strikethrough:hover:after {
 transform: scaleX(0);
 transform-origin: center right;
}
/* Paragrafe */
p{
 font-size:140px;
    text-align:center;
 text-color:white;
 font-family: 'myfont2', sans-serif; 
}
p2{
 font-size:17px;
    text-align:center;
 text-color:white;
 font-family: 'myfont6', sans-serif; 
}
p3{
 font-size:90px;
    text-align:center;
 text-color:white;
 font-family: 'myfont8', sans-serif; 
}
p4{
 font-size:17px;
    text-align:center;
 text-color:white;
 font-family: 'myfont8', sans-serif; 
}
p5{
 font-size:17px;
    text-align:center;
 text-color:white;
 font-family: 'myfont9', sans-serif; 
}
p6{
 font-size:90px;
    text-align:center;
 text-color:white;
 font-family: 'myfont8', sans-serif; 
}
/* test */
```

```html
  <html>
   <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mystyle.css">
   </head>
   <body>
      <header>
         <div class="nav">
            <ul>
               <li>
                  <a href="#home">
                     <span class="strikethrough">
                        <p2>Home</p2>
                     </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#news">
                     <span class="strikethrough">
                        <p2>Projects</p2>
                     </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li>
                  <a href="#contact">
                     <span class="strikethrough">
                        <p2>Contact</p2>
                     </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
               <li style="float:right">
                  <a href="#about">
                     <span class="strikethrough">
                        <p2>About</p2>
                     </span>
                  </a>
               </li>
            </ul>
         </div>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <div class="nume">
            <p3><font style="color:white;padding-left:40px;">C Î R S T O I U  &nbsp B O G D A N</font></p3>
         </div>
         <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
         <div class="nume2">
            <p6><font style="color:white;padding-left:500px;">-&nbsp W h o &nbsp a m &nbsp I ?&nbsp - </font></p6>
         </div>
      </header>
      <main>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
         <p>Test</p>
      </main>
      <footer>
         <div class="nume2" style="padding:15px;">
            <p4><font style="color:white;text-align:center">Cîrstoiu Bogdan - 2018<br> All rights reserved</font></p4>
         </div>
      </footer>
      <script src="/scripts/scripts.js"></script>
   </body>
</html>
```

All i want is a simple way to do it , that works , i've tried some already and they do not work . There is an attempt at doing it in the code shown above , but it doesn't work . If you have any suggestions , please let me know . Thanks !

edit : also , if someone has a tip for how can i make this responsive , please , let me know or guide me to a tutorial !

Comment: If provided answer has helped, etiquette is to mark this as "the answer" and probably upvote its usefulness. 
This prevents this question coming up under "show unanswered questions" in SOF and also gives some more reputation to the person who helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to change the colour of the element nav in your JavaScript. You should really change the colour of the paragraph tag for nested in your nav bar.

I have made a simple example to show the desired behaviour, for simplicity I have removed the font-face.

Another way to approach this is to make the nav bar sticky.

```js
 $(window).scroll(function() {
   var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
   if (scroll > 50) {
   var element = $('.p2');
     $(".p2").css("color", "black");
   } else {
     $(".p2").css("color", "white");
   }
 })
```

```css
 body {
   background-color: white;
   margin: 0;
 }

 header {
   background-color: #6495ED;
   height: 100px;
 }

 footer {
   background-color: black;
   float: bottom;
   color: white;
   width: 100%;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 30px;
 }


 /* Side-nav */

 /* Nav-bar */

 ul {
   list-style-type: none;
   margin: 0;
   padding: 20px;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   width: 100%;
 }

 li {
   float: left;
 }

 li a {
   display: block;
   color: white;
   text-align: center;
   padding: 14px 16px;
   text-decoration: none;
 }

 .menu_white {
   color: white;
 }

 .menu_black {
   color: black;
 }

 .strikethrough {
   display: inline-block;
   position: relative;
   transition: all 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
 }

 .strikethrough: after {
   content: '';
   position: absolute;
   display: block;
   width: 100%;
   height: 2px;
   box-shadow: 0 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
   margin-top: -0.7em;
   background: white;
   transform-origin: center left;
   animation: strikethrough 1s 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1) 1;
   transition: transform 0.5s cubic-bezier(0.55, 0, 0.1, 1);
 }

 @keyframes strikethrough {
   from {
     transform: scaleX(0);
   }

   to {
     transform: scaleX(1);
   }
 }

 .strikethrough:hover: after {
   transform: scaleX(0);
   transform-origin: center right;
 }

 /* Paragrafe */

 p {
   font-size: 140px;
   text-align: center;
   color: black;
 }

 .p2 {
   font-size: 17px;
   text-align: center;
   color: white;
 }

 .p3 {
   font-size: 90px;
   text-align: center;
   color: black;
 }

 .p4 {
   font-size: 17px;
   text-align: center;
   color: black;
 }

 .p5 {
   font-size: 17px;
   text-align: center;
   color: black;
 }

 .p6 {
   font-size: 90px;
   text-align: center;
   color: black;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>

  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#home">
                     <span class="strikethrough">
                        <div class = "p2">Home</div>
                     </span>
                  </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#news">
                     <span class="strikethrough">
                      <div class = "p2">Projects</div>
                     </span>
                  </a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="#contact">
                     <span class="strikethrough">
                     <div class = "p2">Contact</div>
                     </span>
                  </a>
          </li>
          <li style="float:right">
            <a href="#about">
                     <span class="strikethrough">
                     <div class = "p2">About</div>
                     </span>
                  </a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <div class="nume">
        <p3>
          <font style="color:white;padding-left:40px;">C Î R S T O I U &nbsp B O G D A N</font>
        </p3>
      </div>
      <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
      <div class="nume2">
        <p6>
          <font style="color:white;padding-left:500px;">-&nbsp W h o &nbsp a m &nbsp I ?&nbsp - </font>
        </p6>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
      <p>Test</p>
    </main>
    <footer>
      <div class="nume2" style="padding:15px;">
        <p4>
          <font style="color:white;text-align:center">Cîrstoiu Bogdan - 2018<br> All rights reserved</font>
        </p4>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the height and the y axis position of your nav to calculate when yo add a class that has de styling you want, when scrolling.

Something like this.

```
document.addEventListener('scroll', function(){
    var height = document.querySelector(".section-1").offsetHeight;
    // your nav
    var nav = document.querySelector("nav");
    var ypos = window.pageYOffset;

    if(ypos > height) {
        nav.classList.add("fade-in"); //if scrolled passed
    } else {
        nav.classList.remove("fade-in");
    }
});
```

`fade-in` would have the `background-color` you wish.

Hope it helps. Read more about those position properties here for example: [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight)

Hope it helps, regards.